# Insert query parameter into a field

Tags: ampscript, formula-field, form

I am building a web form which is related to another *table* in my data extension. (What I need, is to store the foreign key into a hidden field.)

The easiest way seems to be, that I pass a URL parameter and read it with the QueryParameter function.

**Question:** How do I insert this value into a field in my SmartCapture form?

Best regards,
Benedikt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to write your form from scratch, using [AMPScript](http://help.exacttarget.com/AMPscript/).